# How to get all statuses from a workflow of a project in JIRA via python?

Tags: python, rest, api, jira, project

The closest I've gotten is via the rest API call.

```
https://{HOST}/rest/api/2/project/{Project Key}/statuses
```

But I need the same call via Python. But I'm unable to find an adequate way.
The closest I've gotten in Python is

`jiraInstance.statuses()` but this returns all possible statuses for our Jira site.

I need to narrow it down to the workflows for a specific project.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Background**

This is for a reporting tool where we create a table with all the defects for the specific project in question. In python I can currently retrieve all the statuses/priorities for the Bugs/Bug-task issues but that only returns statuses for the existing bugs. I require a way to retrieve all the statuses from a workflow of the specific project.

Comment: Start at https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-get-all-Jira-statuses-from-a-workflow-of-an-issue-by/qaq-p/461172

Answer (score 2):

This will list all project keys in a given project with their respective status...

```
issues = jira.search_issues('project=projectname')

for issue in issues:
    print (issue.key, 'Status: ',issue.fields.status)
```